# How to edit row using data entry form?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data entry form and data sheets as Table1 and Table2.

In the data entry form, first I have an option to select the data sheet. Then I type an Item in the Item box and save data to that data sheet.

When I enter data for an existing Item, it generates another row and that item goes to the new row so it creates duplicates.

I need to update the existing row in the data data sheet.

```vb
Sub Save_Details()
    
    Dim shTable As Worksheet
    Dim shForm As Worksheet
        
    Dim iCurrentRow As Integer
        
    Dim sTableName As String
        
    Set shForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")
        
    sTableName = shForm.Range("H7").Value
        
    Set shTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sTableName)
        
    iCurrentRow = shTable.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
    With shTable
         
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = iCurrentRow - 1
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = shForm.Range("H9")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = shForm.Range("H11")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 4) = shForm.Range("H13")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 5) = shForm.Range("H15")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 6) = shForm.Range("H17")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 7) = shForm.Range("H19")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 8) = shForm.Range("H21")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 9) = shForm.Range("H23")
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 10) = Application.UserName
            
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 11) = Format([Now()], "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")
            
    End With
    
    shForm.Range("H7, H9, H11, H13, H15, H17, H19, H21, H23").Value = ""
        
    MsgBox "Data saved successfully!"   
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your line

```
iCurrentRow = shTable.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

which always find firs empty row in shTable with

```
Dim vMatched As Variant
iCurrentRow = shTable.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
vMatched = Application.Match(shForm.Range("H9").Value2, shTable.Range("B1:B" & iCurrentRow), 0)
If IsError(vMatched) Then
    iCurrentRow = iCurrentRow + 1
Else
    iCurrentRow = vMatched
End If
```

which will try found value from `shForm.Range("H9")` (is it your item name?). If found, replace the existing one, otherwise add a new one

Comment: Got the Answer sir. Thank you so much sir. God bless you.